# Azure SSIS IR - working with files in the temp folder of the IR node

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have setup a custom SSIS IR, however I'm having problems reading files from the current working directory or temp folder on the IR node

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-files-file-shares?view=sql-server-2017

The work flow of my test package is

- Load compressed file to Azure file share
- Unzip file
- Modify file, saving it the current working group folder on the IR node (this path .\testfile.json)
- Load file to Azure SQL DB

The last step is where I'm having issues, I receive the below error message. Maybe looks to be related to security, but no idea how to access the SSIS IR node to check this.

> Execute SQL Task:Error: Executing the query "DECLARE @request
>   VARCHAR(MAX)  SELECT @request =..." failed with the following error:
>   "Cannot bulk load because the file ".\testfile.json" could not be
>   opened. Operating system error code (null).". Possible failure
>   reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From just the error message, looks like you're using BULK INSERT in Execute SQL Task to load data into Azure SQL DB.  BULK INSERT into Azure SQL DB can only work from Azure Storage Blob, but not from file systems/SSIS IR nodes.  To load data from the current working directory of SSIS IR nodes into Azure SQL DB, you can use a Data Flow with Flat File Source and ADO.NET Destination.

Comment: It's a shame, as Bulk load from a file system seems to be a common ETL operation. Flat File source is not suitable in my case. Also Bulk load from BLOB is not suitable because our files are in a FileShare which also doesnt support Bulk load We really wanted to migrate SSIS packages to the cloud but seems to be so many little work arounds required or changes in code, that really its not worth while for us at the moment...